# Total Amount missing

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, contribution-page

I'm using the latest version of CIVICRM (4.7.12) on the latest version of Joomla (3.6.2). On the online subscription page (http://liberazioneanimale.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&view=Contributions&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&id=1&reset=1&Itemid=941) I can't see the sum corrisponding to the Total Amount (Importo Totale). 
I've created two Membeship Types, selected in membership tab, and added a Minimum Amount in Amount tab. 
Can someone help me to understand what's wrong? thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I'm having the same problem, the total box just remains blank regardless of what is selected above it. Thanks in advance

Comment: It appears to be working correctly -- when I select a membership type it updates the total amount field. When I click on the additional charges, it updates the total amount field to reflect the new total.  What is the issue?

Comment: We are seeing this in version 4.7.13. Does anyone know if this was fixed in a current version?